# Using Powershell to get AllowLogon from AD doesn't always display the correct information

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-4.0, powershell-remoting

I have a script that uses an input file with users SamAccountName. It goes thought the script and updates the users profile to check mark the
**"Deny this user permissions to log on to Remote Desktop Session Host Server".**
Once the value is set I also want to read it to make sure it got changed properly.

For most users it works but for some it will say it changed but it actually is not.

```
   $ADUsers = Get-Content "C:\PSTOOLS\Passwordneverexpire\disable-enbale deny logon.txt"

ForEach ($User in $ADUsers) {
    $UserDN = (Get-ADUser -identity $User).distinguishedName
    if ($UserDN) {
        $Command = [ADSI] "LDAP://$UserDN"
        $Command.psbase.invokeSet("AllowLogon",0) # it will NOT allow remote logon
        $Command.setinfo()
        Write-Host $User + "Allow logon " + $Command.psbase.InvokeGet("AllowLogon") -as [Boolean]
    }
    else {
        Write-Host "$UserDN Does Not Exist"
    }
}
```

[image: Check Deny this user permissions to log on to Remote Desktop Session Host Server]

Comment: It may be due to how fast it's running through the list. Try adding a `start-sleep`.

Comment: I don't think this will fix it because if we run it for that one account still shows the wrong result.

Comment: You need to refresh the user data after setting with another `Command = [ADSI] "LDAP://$UserDN"`.

Comment: Hi Theo, Your command got cut off. I don't see the full text.

Comment: I don't think you need to refresh the `$Command ` object after running `.SetInfo()`.  I haven't been able to reproduce your problem.  I presume if the object needed to be refreshed the problem would be visual only and consistent rather than true and intermittent.  You haven't explained why you think it isn't working.

Comment: Also: The `Write-Host` command doesn't look correct. Maybe something like: `Write-Host $User "Allow logon :" ([Boolean]$Command.PSBase.InvokeGet("AllowLogon")) ` will be cleaner...  Note: you're citing `$User` which is still an ADObject, `Write-Host` will implicitly run that through `.ToString()` and output the DN.  However, if that's what you wanted, you already have the $UserDN variable...  Moreover, Using something else, like the samAccountName, might make for easier reading.

Comment: Indeed, the dollar sign got cut off.. Right after the line `$Command.setinfo()`, refresh the info with another `$Command = [ADSI] "LDAP://$UserDN"`. (BTW, I'd use a different variable name instead of `$Command`.. Perhaps `$userInfo` would be more appropriate.

Comment: Hi Steven and Theo,

Comment: Hi Steven and Theo, Thank you for your response. I think I found what the problem is. Once you run $Command.psbase.invokeSet("AllowLogon",0) than no matter if the value of $Command is 0 or is actually 1 it will always return 0 when you InvokeGet the value. The problem is refreshing the data without setting it to get the proper current value of "AllowLogon".

Comment: I tried using a differed variable like $userInfo but the result is always the same.

Comment: Hi All, We're using a domain admin account to set "AllowLogon" value but we're getting access denied when we try to manually set the value from the UI on some accounts. Powershell is not showing any error messages. I tried to use try{}catch{}  but no luck. Is there a way we can see that error?

Answer (score 0):

AllowLogon has 3 state possible :

1. Enabled        = $true
2. Disabled       = $False
3. Never Defined  = ERROR on read !

you can use this code

```
 $AdsiItem = [adsi]"LDAP://$($item.DistinguishedName)"
 try {
     $AllowLogon = $AdsiItem.InvokeGet("AllowLogon")
 } catch {
     # unreadable, because it is never defined
     $AllowLogon = $Null
 }

 if($AllowLogon -eq $true) {
     'TSE authorized!'
 } elseif ($null -eq $AllowLogon ) {
     'TSE not forbidden!'
 } else {
     'Forbidden!'
 }
```